# After Calling web services - getting null value for some property

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

We are using CXF web services.

Scenario:

one service call is returing `List<NoteDTO>` .
Data was there `NoteDTO` but after calling web services method which is returing List
we are seeing null values in `NoteDTO` class.

there is no any kind of Exceptions in Logs also.

My understanding is there is convertion problem in Webservices.

```
public class NoteDTO {


    /** The text of the note. */
    private String text;

    /** The date the note was created. */
    private Date created;

    /** The user who created the note. */
    private UserDTO createdBy;

    /** The date the note was last modified. */
    private Date modified;

    /** The last user to modify the note. */
    private UserDTO modifiedBy;


    private String wfStep;  

    public void setWfStep(String wfStep) {
        this.wfStep = wfStep;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor for JAXB.
     */
    public NoteDTO() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor taking basic values.
     * @param text The text of the note.
     * @param created The date created.
     * @param createdBy The user who create the note.
     */
    public NoteDTO(String text, Date created, UserDTO createdBy) {
        this.text = text;
        this.created = created;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;     
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the text of the note.
     * @return The text of the note.
     */
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the text of the note.
     * @param text The text of the note.
     */
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the created date.
     * @return The created date.
     */
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the created date.
     * @param created The create date.
     */
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the modified date.
     * @return The modified date.
     */
    public Date getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the modified date.
     * @param modified The modified date.
     */
    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the created by user.
     * @return The created by user.
     */
    public UserDTO getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the created by user.
     * @param createdBy The created by user.
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(UserDTO createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the modified by user.
     * @return The modified by user.
     */
    public UserDTO getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the modified by user.
     * @param modifiedBy The modified by user.
     */
    public void setModifiedBy(UserDTO modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the workflow step.
     * @return The workflow step.
     */
    public String getWfstep() {
        return this.wfStep;
    }
```

I have a web services class

```
@WebService
public interface NotesService {

    /**
     * Get server notes for a specific workflow instance
     * @param workflowInstanceEntitityId Workflow Instance Entity ID
     * @return A list of notes.
     */
    List<NoteDTO> getNotesForWorkflowInstance(String bundleName, String workflowInstanceName);
}
```

the data was there at other side in NoteDTO but after call like below

```
notes = notesService.getNotesForWorkflowInstance(bundleName, workflowInstanceName);
```

I am getting wfStep property value as null

Any thoughts?

thansk in advance.

Comment: some sort of code would help...

Answer (score 0):

may be **@WebMethod** annotation will help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the appropriate annotations on your classes so I assume you are using Java-First approach.

I am definitely sure that your `NoteDTO` is not the `XSD` schema of your `WSDL` types. If you are generating `WSDL` from java code using `CXF` what you need to do is to add the appropriate annotations on the web service' objects. So your `NoteDTO` class should be something like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "NoteDTO", propOrder = {
    "text",
    "created",
    "createdBy",
    "modified",
    "modifiedBy",
    "wfStep"
})
public class NoteDTO {

    @XmlElement(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @XmlElement(name = "created")
    private Date created;

    @XmlElement(name = "createdBy")
    private UserDTO createdBy;

    @XmlElement(name = "modified")
    private Date modified;

    @XmlElement(name = "modifiedBy")
    private UserDTO modifiedBy;

    @XmlElement(name = "wfStep")
    private String wfStep;  

}
```

The same with `UserDTO` and any other objects used in your web services calls. Then your interface should look something like this:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://your.target.namespace/", name = "NotesService")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface NotesService {

    @WebResult(name = "getNotesForWorkflowInstanceResponse", targetNamespace = "http://your.target.namespace/")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getNotesForWorkflowInstance", action = "http://your.target.namespace/getNotesForWorkflowInstance")
    public List<NoteDTO> getNotesForWorkflowInstance(
        @WebParam(name = "bundleName", targetNamespace = "http://your.target.namespace/") String bundleName,
        @WebParam(name = "workflowInstanceName", targetNamespace = "http://your.target.namespace/") String workflowInstanceName        
    );

}
```

Not tested, just added everything by hand. Read more about the Java-First approach and you'll find out what you're doing wrong. This is just a hint to get started.